# c# find in text something or something

Tags: c#, text, find, richtextbox

I need to search in text, but is it possible to have more than one option in `richtextbox.Find("something");`? For example `richtextbox.Find("something" or "somethingelse");`

Comment: for strings  .contains("part of text") does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement something like this (an *extension method* `FindAny` for `RichTextBox`):

```
  public static class RichTextBoxExtensions {
    public static int FindAny(this RichTextBox source, params String[] toFind) {
      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
      else if (null == toFind)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("toFind");

      int result = -1;

      foreach (var item in toFind) {
        if (null == item)
          continue;

        int v = source.Find(item);

        if ((v >= 0) && ((result < 0) || (v < result)))
          result = v;
      }

      return result;
    }
  }

....

  int result = richtextbox.FindAny("something", "somethingelse");
```

Comment: Working. Thanks. But the third line from the bottom must be 'return v;', not 'return = v;'

Comment: @Stepik: yes, you're quite right; sorry for typo. It should be `result = v;`, I've edited the answer.